# How to sum powers of 2 with while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to calculate the sum of `2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^n`, where `n` is a number entered by the user. The main problem is that I don't know how to use the while loop to sum the different result of `2^n` up.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfThePowers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a power: ");
        int power = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        int number = 2; 
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        while(power <= i) {
            Math.pow(number, i);
            sum = sum + Math.pow(number, i);
            i = i + 1;
        }

        int result = (int)Math.pow(number, i);
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input, expected output, actual output?

Comment: Remove the `Math.pow(number, i);` on its own line. That does nothing. Why don't you use `sum` after the loop?

Comment: you can just return 2^(n+1) - 1... gives the same answer :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking us to do your homework for you. Try stepping through the code with a debugger and looking at what it's actually doing at each step.

Comment: For non-negative `n`, 2^n is the same thing as `1L << n`.  If you must perform the computation as a genuine sum of separate powers, then computing each power this way is much better than using `Math.pow()`.

Comment: @DylanMeeus the moment of confidence followed by crushing doubt had me delete my comment already...

Comment: @JohnBollinger based on the way OP formulated the series, it looks like the case where n < 0 is undefined anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fine, just a few changes.
Change the parts code to

```
        System.out.println("Type a power: ");
        int power = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int number = 2;
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;
/*Remove this -------->  while(power <= i) {*/
        while (i <= power) {//it should be this
/*Remove this ------->   Math.pow(number, i);*/
            sum = sum + Math.pow(number, i);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

Only you have to do is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfThePowers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a power: ");
        int power = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        double sum = Math.pow(2,power+ 1 ) - 1;
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

    }
}
```

In this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-to-prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-of-powers-of-2-by-induction) explains the math expresion

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional is backwards, it should read:

```
while (i <= power)
```

Answer (score 0):

You compute the sum of powers, then completely ignore it, just printing out the result of 2^i.  you should be printing out sum, something like:

```
while (i <= power) {
   sum += Math.pow(number, i);
   i++;
}
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

For style points this won't handle a negative power, so you'll need to test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand why do you want to loop in this case. You can do it like :

```
System.out.println("The sum is: "+(Math.pow(2, power+1)-1 ));
```

But if you really want to use loop try this :

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a power: ");
        int power = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        int number = 2; 
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        while(i<=power) {
            sum = sum + Math.pow(number, i);
            i = i + 1;
        }

        int result = (int)Math.pow(number, i);
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with comments to explain the logic.  While loops need some kind of variable to control the number of iterations.  That variable of course needs to be updated somewhere *inside* the loop.

You can compute the sum of the powers with the Math.pow() function, obviously.  No import statement is needed to use it.  I hope this helps.  Good luck.

```
    /* Scanner and variable to get and hold user input */
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    int userInput = 0;

    /* Variable to hold the sum, initialized to 0.0 */
    double sum = 0.0;

    /* Prompt the user, and obtain the reply */
    System.out.print( "Enter the exponent: ");
    userInput = scan.nextInt();

    /* The while loop and it's initialized counter */
    int counter = 0;    
    while( counter <= userInput ){

        /* Add each power to sum using Math.pow() */
        sum = sum + Math.pow( 2, counter );

        /* Watch the output as the loop runs */
        System.out.println( "Sum: " + sum );

        counter++;  // Increment counter, so the loop exits properly

    } // End while loop
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SumofSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String c = "123";
        char d[] = c.toCharArray();
        int a[] = new int[d.length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
            a[i] = d[i] - 48;

        int r = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
            r = r + (int) Math.pow(a[i], a[i + 1]);

        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your code, and keep in mind that the OP asked for a `while` loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfThePowers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Type a number:");
        int power=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int number=2;
        int i=0;
        int result=0;
        while (power>=i) {
            result += (int)Math.pow(number, i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("The result is "+result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfThePowers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a number:");
    double power=Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());
    int number=2;
    int i=0;
    double sum=0;
    while (power>=i) {
        sum=sum+Math.pow(number, i);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);

}
```